# How to avoid data snooping when doing a leave-one-subject-out train-test split?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, data-leakage

I have 13 subjects, and I am trying to create a model which can do well on unseen subjects. The problem is that, when I leave one subject for the test set and train the model on others, the accuracy of the model highly depend on the selected subject for the test.

I can do a train-test split 13 times, leaving every subject for the test once and only once. Then I can average the results.

However, it is a machine learning principle that one should not tune the parameters based on test results. This is why we have a validation set.

Of course, for each of the 13 train-test splits, I can create a leave-one-subject-out cross validation set. That is, one subject will be out for the test; from the remaining 12 subjects, each of them will be a validation set (like a 12-fold cross validation).

So, the average (over 13) of the average (over 12) cross validation results is a predictor for the test results.

Here comes the big problem: Isn't there a data leakage here? When **subject X** is left out for the test, and **subject Y** is selected for validation, and the others for training, the results will be very similar to the case when **subject Y** is chosen for the test, and the others for training.

How can I do a model selection and parameter tuning without data snooping?

Comment: Look up nested cross validation. It is basically what you want to do, though with only 13 data points your results are going to be pretty poor regardless of what you do.

Comment: @astel thanks for the comment. The subjects are not data points; many data points were collected from each subject.